# I want to make two ways that outbound to TCP client

Tags: routes, spring-integration

I am configuring Spring integration setting. There are two TCP servers and it's outbound-channel that shares same channel.

I want the channel to be routed using the header's value. How can I solve this?

```
<ip:tcp-connection-factory id="admMsgRcvServer"
    type="server" port="#{afiProperties.admMsgRcvPort}" deserializer="byteArrayCharLengthSerializer"
    serializer="byteArrayCharLengthSerializer" single-use="true" />

<ip:tcp-connection-factory id="simMsgSndClient"
    type="client" host="#{afiProperties.msgSndHost}" port="#{afiProperties.msgSndPort}"
    single-use="true" so-timeout="10000" deserializer="byteArrayCharLengthSerializer"
    serializer="byteArrayCharLengthSerializer" />

<ip:tcp-outbound-channel-adapter id="msgSnd" 
    connection-factory="simMsgRcvServer" channel="afiHeadToHeaderChannel"  />   

<ip:tcp-outbound-channel-adapter id="simMsgSnd"
    channel="afiHeadToHeaderChannel" connection-factory="simMsgSndClient" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an  to route to a channel based on the value of a header.

```
<int:header-value-router header-name="foo">
    <int:mapping value="fooValue1" channel="channel1"/>
    <int:mapping value="fooValue2" channel="channel2"/>
</int:header-value-router>
```

That said, one of your adapters uses a "server" connection factory; that won't work as configured. You can't send arbitrary messages to a connection created by a server connection factory; it usually has to be a reply to an incoming message; there are some advanced techniques to do it, but you always need at least one incoming message first.

Comment: So, you mean that I have to use it with a "client" connection factory. right? thank you!